# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
if ($_GET['section'] == 'task' && isset($_GET['setstatus']) && isset($_GET['task_id']))
{
    if ($_GET['setstatus'] == 1 || $_GET['setstatus'] == 0 && is_numeric($_GET['task_id']))
    {

        $tsdata = [':status' => $_GET['setstatus'], ':id' => $_GET['task_id']];
        $result = $mysql->query("UPDATE  `u387857933_user`.`task` SET  `tstatus` = :status WHERE  `task`.`id` =:id;", $tsdata);
        //var_dump($result);

    }
}
```

Ошибка: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053

Что не так то ?!
Класс mysql:

```
<?
class Mysql {

    private $db;
    private $config;

    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->config = include __DIR__ .'/config.php';
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$this->config['dbname']};host={$this->config['dbhost']}", $this->config['dbuser'], $this->config['dbpassword']);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('<b>Ошбика при подключении к базе данных</b>:     '  . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function query($sql, $params=[])
    {
        try {
            $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $sth->execute($params);
            return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die('<b>Ошбика при выполнение запроса QUERY</b>:   ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: А есть текстовка ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что после `Update` нечего выбирать. Там не возвращается массив, а значит на строке `$sth->fetchAll` все и ломается.

Если нужно посмотреть статусы исполнения операции Update, то надо возвращать это непосредственно из `$sth`

```
$rv = $sth->execute(...
return $rv;
```

Однако возникнут проблемы с другими запросами. Поэтому, как правило, разделяют методы для разных видов запросов, где для `update` не будет никаких `$sth->fetchAll`

Comment: Может тогда делать проверку ? 
Типа если $sth массив, то return делаем если нет. то не делаем ? так ?или нет

Comment: @cr1gger да, но нет.... я уже написал, что надо разделять. В итоге это придется делать, ибо одним `query` не обойтись.........По сути, я имею в виду драйвер БД. где у тебя будут методы для разных запросов.... ....в твоём случае с `query` возможно в качестве доп параметра передавать тип запроса `update/select/delete/insert` и в зависимости от этого уже действовать.........но в итоге поищи драйверы поразбирай их. в будущем понадобится.

Comment: Да мне пока и кастыль пойдет.
Смотри я сделал так
  $r = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if (is_array($r))
    {
     return $r;
    }
Все равно ошибку выдает

Comment: @cr1gger так а зачем ты снова написал `$sth->fetchAll`? я же черным по белому написал, что не возвращает `update` никаких строк.. только `true/false`...нечего извлекать через `fetchAll`.....костыль, раз хочешь: `public function query($sql, $type, $params=[]) {...... if ($type == 'select' && $res !== false)
            return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);.....` .....и для запросов давай параметр, например `$mysql->query("UPDATE  \`task\` SET  \`tstatus\` = :status WHERE  \`id\` =:id;", 'update', $tsdata);` ....... или `$mysql->query("SELECT * FROM \`task\`" , 'select');`